# PHP for loop increment by 100000

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to loop through `$i` which starts from 790000000 and echo every 100000 up to 799999999:

790000000
790100000
790200000
790300000
790400000
...

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
for ($i=790000000; $i<=800000000; $i+100000) {
    echo $i . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I am shocked, by seeing this question and reputation you are having!

Comment: Should go to basics!

Answer (score 2):

For loop wrong code, you are missing actual code update as `$i+100000` does not update variable. Use `$i += 100000` instead.

```
//                                Here is problem in your code
for ($i=790000000; $i<=800000000; $i += 100000) {
    echo $i . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your loop using `+=` instead of `i`.
Only using `+` will not increment your `$i` variable value.

```
for ($i=790000000; $i<=800000000; $i+=100000) {
    echo $i . '<br>';
}
```